# The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found in NetStandard Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, nuget-package, class-library

Visual Studio 2017.

I create a separate Class Library (.Net Standard) Project.
Go to Manage NuGet Packages and look for Entity Framework, find it and install it (6.4).
Add a class to this project with the below code

```
public class StoreContext : DbContext
{
}
```

Error: *The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

I add `using System.Data.Entity;`

I now get *The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

I then decide to try and add `System.Data` but when i go into the references option, under assemblies i see

*no framework assemblies were found on this machine*

What am i missing?

Comment: Did you add the using directives? Normally you would have to provide the fully qualified name for every type you are using. But using direcetives allow you to skip that. And I am unsure why you think a System Namespace would have anything to do with a third party dll.

Comment: Are you missing the NuGet package using statements at top of module?

Comment: System.Data is what i was referring to. The only using statement i have at present is  using System; adding using System.Data.Entity; throws the above error. Which reference are you guys suggesting i should have? Usually the "Quick Actions" bulb advises what references i may be missing but nothing listed there other than creating a new DbContext Class?

Comment: Quick Action suggests missing namespaces, not references. if reference is not added to project, it'll not suggest missing namespace

Answer (score -1):

You need to add reference to EntityFramework library in your project

Comment: I've already added this as per my original post. I even uninstalled and reinstalled it

Comment: You mentioned you've installed entity framework through nuget package, but  didnt add reference to it.
Can you see EntityFramework under the References, in visual studio?
Can u post the screenshot of the References?